# WPF link button

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a button control to which I want add image as well as hyperlink property, i.e it should be an image button with link to other source. I tried

```
<Button Click="OnNavigationRequest"  ToolTip="Orkut">
  <Image Source="C:\Documents and Settings\SaurabhS\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008   \Projects\SaurabhSinhaDemos\WPF_Zone\AddressBook\AddressBook\images\orkut.jpeg"/>
  <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.orkut.com">Orkut</Hyperlink>
</Button>
```

and in code behind:

```
 AddHandler(Hyperlink.RequestNavigateEvent, 
            new RoutedEventHandler(OnNavigationRequest));

 public void OnNavigationRequest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          var source = e.OriginalSource as Hyperlink;
          if (source != null)
              Process.Start(source.NavigateUri.ToString());
      }
```

But got the following error:

> content set more than once...

How should I do it?

Comment: You have not given us the full XAML code. The error message you cite says that there is an error in your XAML code, where there's more than one child element within an element that can only take one child element. Please post the full XAML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
  <Button>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizantal">
       <Image Source="path to the image"/>
       <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.orkut.com"/>
     </StackPanel>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `Button` element contains two child elements. The `Button` element can only take one child element.

Wrap `Image` and `Hyperlink` in a `StackPanel` or some other layout container and the error will go away (see Int3's answer for an example).